# How can I set the internal time of the PHP interpreter?

Tags: php, datetime

I have written a function in PHP which will print the third Monday of every month.
I now want to test the function if the function will work next month, without having to wait till next month.

My idea is that I could test how the function would work in the future by internally setting PHP's time to next month and running the function.

I was hoping there would be a [Date Time ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php) which I could insert  before my  function to shift the time into the future, something like

```
<?php

$one_month_from_now = time() + 2592000;
ini_set('php_internal_time', $one_month_from_now);

function print_third_monday() {
    // ....
}
print_third_monday();
```

Is is possible to change PHP's internal time like this? if so, how?

Comment: PHP gets its time from the server it runs on but you can create a `DateTime` instance or unix timestamp for any date you want, eg `$ts = strtotime('April, 2017')`

Comment: @Phil, if I understand,  you are saying, in the locations, where I have used `$c = time()` and or `$c = new DateTime;` I would replace those "current time" variables with `$c = strtotime('April, 2017')`?

Comment: Yes, something like that. The `DateTime` constructor can take the same string arguments as `strtotime`

Comment: @Phil thanks, yes your original comment will give me the solution I was going for, I will just have to refactor a bit but I think it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("y-m-d H:i:s D");//17-03-16 10:43:38 Thu
echo PHP_EOL;
echo date("y-m-d H:i:s D",strtotime("+1 month"));//17-04-16 10:43:38 Sun
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a better function that does the same functionality & you can cross check with ease:

```
<?php
echo getThirdTuesdayofMonth(3,2017);

function getThirdTuesdayofMonth($month, $year) {
    $thirdTuesday='';
    $no_of_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $tue_iter=0;
    for($i=1;$i<=$no_of_days;$i++) {
        if(date('l',strtotime($i.'-'.$month.'-'.$year))=='Tuesday') {
            if($tue_iter==3) {
                $thirdTuesday = date('dS F Y', strtotime($i.'-'.$month.'-'.$year));
            }  
            $tue_iter++; 
        }
    }
    return $thirdTuesday;
}
```